# How to create array<string> from array<string> in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a arrayA

```
var arrayA = ["1111|0000-01-30|123456|CUSTOMER", "1111|0000-01-30|123457|CUSTOMER", "1111|0000-01-30|123458|CUSTOMER"];
```

How can i slipt "|" to array B

```
var arrayB= ["123456","123457","123458"]
```

How can i do? I don't want to use for loop.

Comment: _I don't want to use for loop_ - Why ever not if it proves to be the most sensible approach? Also, what have you already tried?

Comment: because performance  when loop large arrayA.

Comment: How about changing the way you receive the data so you don't have to split it in the first place? That might mean you have to change how you store the data, but that seems to be the real problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Select` to transform each splitted string into its third element and collect to an array:

```
arrayA.Select(s => s.Split('|')[2]).ToArray();
```

`using System.Linq;` required.

Comment: Aren't code only answers frowned upon? I agree it is correct, but the OP might not be aware that he has to include `using System.Linq;` or how your current solution "works"

Comment: @Icepickle included some explanation to take into account your suggestion.